# When testing smartmenus in Selenium, submenus do not get exposed on hover over

Tags: selenium, mouseover

Standard Selenium mouseover / hover mechanism does not work

```
Actions builder = new Actions(driver);                 
builder.click(actionsButton).moveToElement(addNewLink).build().perform();
```

However, click action unexpectedly works:

```
Actions builder = new Actions(driver);  
builder.click(actionsButton).click(addNewLink).build().perform();
```

Which is the exact opposite of what happens when a user navigates the menus - they get exposed on hover over and closed on click.

Answer (score 2):

The culprit turns out to be [Smartmenus](http://www.smartmenus.org/). It has a non-standard code that uses absence of a mouse to detect mobile devices. When a mobile device is detected, Smartmenus stops recognizing hover over and instead begins responding to click/tap.

Whatever Selenium does to simulate the mouse movement does not convince Smartmenus that the real mouse is present.

Switching to click instead of hover over also does not work reliably in cases where a user moves the mouse on the computer running Selenium tests.

I've settled for a workaround that tries to click and, if unsuccessful, switches to hover over:

```
    Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
    builder.click(actionsButton).click(addNewLink).build().perform();
    try {
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(pcLink));
    }
    catch (TimeoutException e) {
        builder.click(actionsButton).moveToElement(addNewLink).build().perform();
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(pcLink));
    }
    pcLink.click();
```

Comment: Maybe changing the user agent of selenium would have done the trick.